# Places API restrict result such that there is no country name

Tags: android, google-places-api

I need to restrict the result of places api such that the country name shouldnt be there in the description in JSON result.

```
String input="";
        try {
            input = "input=" + URLEncoder.encode(place[0], "utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        String types = "types=geocode";
        String sensor = "sensor=false";
        String parameters = input+"&"+types+"&"+sensor+"&"+key;
        String output = "json";
        String GOOGLE_MAPS_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/"+output+"?"+parameters;
```

On searching I get result as 
Indianapolis, IN, United States.
Is there a way i could get a result ommiting the country name?

like: Indianapolis, IN.

Comment: Show json response which getting from api

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7ZyJXjD4   here is the json what i recieve